# Python - Sum values in nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dict as follows.

```
inv = {'jan':[10,20],'Feb':[33,40,50],'mar':[20,56],'apr':[20,21,30]}
    for value in inv.items():
print(sum(inv.values()))
```

I want the sum of the values to be returned as total.

The total should be 300

Comment: So break down the problem. Do you know how to sum an individual value list? Do you know how to loop over all values?

Comment: This is *really trivial* with a little looping. Have you tried anything yourself yet, did you get stuck anywhere?

Comment: I am able to get the sum of the individual value list                                     inv = {'jan':[10,20],'Feb':[33,40,50],'mar':[20,56],'apr':[20,21,30]}
for key, values in inv.items():
    print(key, sum(value))

Comment: so how would you go about summing all those individual sums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of lists from the values. Then sum the list of lists

```
inv = {'jan':[10,20],'Feb':[33,40,50],'mar':[20,56],'apr':[20,21,30]}
    sumList = []
    for key in inv:
        sumList.append(inv[key])

    print sum(sum(x) for x in sumList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the keys in your dict

```
keys = list(inv.keys())
```

You can use that list to then loop through the keys to get their values and loop those lists to get the sum.

```
total = 0
for key in keys:
    for val in inv[key]:
        total += val
print(total)

300
```